# how can submit a form after some delay

Tags: forms, codeigniter

I have a form in HTML and I'd like to submit this form after 4000ms ,from when the document is ready, without click the submit button. but i need my hidden data in controller while submitting 
how can it possible ? please help me?

```
  <form  action="<?echo base_url();?>register/form_success" method="post" class="form-horizontal" id="career_submitform">
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <span class="caption-title">Please complete the registration form for getting the admission application number</span>

                            </div>
                            <input type="hidden" value="<? echo $applicant_id?>" name="applicant_id"> 
                            <input type="hidden" value="<? echo $grade_name?>" name="grade_name"> 
                            <input type="hidden" value="<? echo $grade_id?>" name="grade_id">
                            <div class="form-actions clearfix">
                                <div class="btncontinue-wrap">
                                    <input type="submit" value="Continue" name="submit" class="btn-d btn-continue blue button-next" id="button_submit_style">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

Comment: So better you have to use AJAX

Comment: use Jquery **delay()** function.

Answer (score 1):

Use Jquery to make delay

```
$(function() {
    $('#career_submitform').delay(2000).submit();
});
```

Comment: the page do not redirect

Answer (score 1):

Then use like this.
html part:

```
<form id="career_submitform">
    <input type="text">
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

script part:

```
$("#career_submitform").submit(function (e) {
    var form = this;
    e.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(function () {
        form.submit();
    }, 1000);
    $("<p>Working...</p>").appendTo("form");
});
```

Check http://jsfiddle.net/eoko1ap4/

Answer (score 0):

```
 <form  action="<?echo base_url();?>register/form_success" method="post" class="form-horizontal" id="career_submitform">
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <span class="caption-title">Please complete the registration form for getting the admission application number</span>

                            </div>
                            <input type="hidden" value="<? echo $applicant_id?>" name="applicant_id"> 
                            <input type="hidden" value="<? echo $grade_name?>" name="grade_name"> 
                            <input type="hidden" value="<? echo $grade_id?>" name="grade_id">
                            <div class="form-actions clearfix">
                                <div class="btncontinue-wrap">
                                    <input  type="button" onclick="myFunction()"  value="Continue" name="submit" class="btn-d btn-continue blue button-next" id="button_submit_style">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>

<script>
function myFunction() {
     $('#career_submitform').delay(4000).submit();
}
</script>
```